# Using #defined values in Visual Studio dialog resource scripts?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, dialog, embedded-resource

I'm trying to create an About box for my Windows C++ application. In Visual Studio 2008, I'm using the dialog editor to design the dialog. I want the About box to display the application's version in a static label.

I can hardcode the version into the dialog, stored in a `.rc` file, but then I'll have to remember to update the version in multiple places.

My application version is `#define`d in `version.h` as `APPLICATION_VERSION`. The resource editor can be convinced to put

```
#include "version.h"
```

at the top of the `.rc` file, so I have access to the `APPLICATION_VERSION` symbol.

However, I cannot use this symbol from the dialog editor. I can edit the `.rc` file by hand, replacing the hardcoded version string by the symbol `APPLICATION_VERSION`. That works fine until I edit the dialog in the dialog editor again: upon saving the `.rc` from the dialog editor, the symbol gets overwritten with its current value.

Of course, I can set the version label to some dummy text, overriding that text when I receive `WM_INITDIALOG`, but that feels very clunky and unnecessary. Is there any other workaround that allows me to keep the application version in a single place?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to put the resource in a separate file with a `.rc2` extension, and `#include` that into the `.rc` file (like you're doing with your `version.h`).  I then edit the `.rc2` files with a normal text editor, not the Visual Studio resource editor.

That system's not too bad for `VERSIONINFO` resources, which is what I use it for, but I can see it would be more of a pain for dialog resources.  I'd love to hear of a better way, but I don't know of one.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm having the same problem with my VERSIONINFO resources. But those are indeed easy enough to edit by hand, so as long as I don't touch the resource editor for those, I'm fine.